# Ethereum ERC-20トークンを受け取るスマートコントラクトのトークンの扱い方がわからない

Tags: ethereum

以下のサイトを参考にERC２０トークンを試しています

https://qiita.com/sinsinpurin/items/e95f7e167b3116d29c68#allowance

このサイトの内容は確認できました
そこで今度は、トークンを受け取って何か処理することにしました
何か処理するというところは、「指定量のトークンをOwnerに戻す」ということにします

`MyTokenICO`へ以下の処理を加えました

```
event MoveToken(address beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

function moveToken() external payable {
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);
    _weiRaised = _weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
    _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _MOCOwner, tokens);
    emit MoveToken(msg.sender, weiAmount, tokens);
}
```

前出のサイトの手順により100トークン持っているので、内50トークン戻すことにします

```
> MT.approve(accounts[1], 50)

> MICO.moveToken.sendTransaction({from: accounts[1], value: 50})
```

ここでエラーになりました

```
Thrown:
{ Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance -- Reason given: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance.
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:16
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:288:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:14)
    at runScript (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.20.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:222:1)
    at Console.interpret (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.20.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:237:1)
    at ReplManager.interpret (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.20.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/repl.js:129:1)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:656:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:937:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:715:7)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:184:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline.js:424:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
  reason: 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance',
  hijackedStack:
   'Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance -- Reason given: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance.\n    at Object.ErrorResponse
以下省略します
```

エラーは`_token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _MOCOwner, tokens);`の箇所で起きています
対応方法や参考情報いただけないでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました
実行方法がよくありませんでした

`MT.approve(accounts[1], 50)`ではなく、
`MT.approve(MICO.address, 50, {from: accounts[1]})`が正しい

理解不足で失礼しました